# Kotlin File.deleteRecursively() doesn't work on cacheDir

Tags: android, kotlin, delete-file

I'm trying to delete the app's cache subfolder (or even the cache folder itself), but nothing happens.

```
cacheFolder = File(this.cacheDir, "/download")
deleteFolder(cacheFolder)

private fun deleteFolder(fileOrDirectory : File){
    fileOrDirectory.deleteRecursively()
}
```

The one-liner doesn't work too

```
this.cacheDir.deleteRecursively()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The `File.deleteRecursively()` function unfortunately doesn't tell you the reason for failure to delete. It just returns true or false to show whether the deletion was successful. If it returns false, the directory tree may have been partly deleted.

Instead of using the old `java.io.File` class, which this function is a Kotlin extension of, it is preferable to use the "newer" `java.nio` utility classes because these will throw an IOException that describes the reason for failure to delete. Unfortunately, Kotlin does not currently provide a `deleteRecursively()` function that uses `java.nio`. It only provides a non-recursive `deleteExisting()` function on the `Path` class. So, you could instead write your own `Path.deleteRecursively()` extension function to live alongside `Path.deleteExisting()`:

```
import java.io.IOException
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Path
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes
import kotlin.io.path.deleteExisting

fun Path.deleteRecursively() {
    Files.walkFileTree(
        this,
        object : SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            override fun visitFile(file: Path, attrs: BasicFileAttributes?): FileVisitResult {
                file.deleteExisting()
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE
            }

            override fun postVisitDirectory(dir: Path, exc: IOException?): FileVisitResult {
                if (exc != null)
                    throw exc
                dir.deleteExisting()
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE
            }
        }
    )
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
import kotlin.io.path.Path
...
   Path(cacheDir).deleteRecursively()
```

and if it fails to delete the whole tree, you'll see a stack trace with an exception and a descriptive message.

**Update:**
The forthcoming Kotlin 1.8.0 will include an experimental function by the same name in its standard library.

Comment: When I call Path(cacheDir).deleteRecursively() the IDE sais me that Interface Path does not have constructors

Comment: @VíctorMartín you need to `import kotlin.io.path.Path`.

Answer (score 1):

It will be better if you use a service to delete the cacheFiles

This is how I did

```
class DeleteCache(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) :
    Worker(context, workerParams) {
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        return try {
            applicationContext.cacheDir?.let {
                if (it.exists()) {
                    val entries = it.listFiles()
                    if (entries != null) {
                        for (entry in entries) {
                            entry.delete()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Result.success()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Result.failure()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't delete any non-empty subdirectories, and it won't tell you if it encounters an error deleting a file, because [entry.delete()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#delete()) doesn't throw an IOException. Otherwise, it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for support. Now I got it working. The problem was the DownloadManager

```
    val url = "$targetUrlFTP/$appName/$downloadingObject/$onlineVer.zip"
    val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes((DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE or 
           DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI))

    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, cacheFolder.toString(), 
           zipFileName)

    val manager = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    downloadID = manager.enqueue(request)
```

the line `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, cacheFolder.toString(),  zipFileName)`completely messed up the path.

Now I have

```
cacheFolder = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)!!
zipFile = File(cacheFolder, zipFileName)
...
request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(zipFile))
```

and everything works. Even

```
private fun deleteFolder(fileOrDirectory : File){
    fileOrDirectory.deleteRecursively()
}
```

does.

Next step is to implement `java.nio`. Thank you Klitos for updating your post. I had no idea how to use it.